# How can I get old Android updates again after a hard reset?

Tags: updates, factory-reset, htc

I have an AT&T HTC that was running Marshmallow 6.0.1 and Sense 7. That's the last update my phone will ever get since it's an older model. I factory reset it to wipe it clean, which returned the software to Lollipop 5.0.2 and Sense 6. I've checked for updates in the settings and it tells me it's up to date even though it's not. Do I just need to wait a few days to get the update notifications? Or do I have to take it to AT&T and have them update it? Or do I have to flash marshmallow myself?

Model HTC Desire Eye

Build 2.09.502.3

Comment: It's unlikely that a factory reset can reset OS version. Can't help but wonder what you did prior to that. Anyway, I do recommend manual flashing.

Comment: Maybe it didn't, but I do know the interface doesn't look the same and I can't find certain apps in the Play Store because its downgraded. Do I have to root the phone before I flash it? I would rather not go through the rooting process...

Comment: Interface downgrade is possible, since HTC moved quite a bit of Sense apps to Play Store (even including the most central part, Blinkfeed!). Get them from Play if that's all you want. On the other hand, flashing does not require root, but does involve getting drivers right and finding a proper firmware, and for amateurs those troubles aren't exactly less than rooting.

Comment: Is there anyway you help me with flashing it? I really dislike the old interface. I've searched up and down and finding the right tools and firmware for my phone is pretty confusing to me.

Comment: By "interface" do you only mean the homescreen (launcher) or anything else? To help you with flashing a lot of details have to be provided, enough to be made into another question (which could be duplicate anyway).

Comment: It's biggest noticeable change is the lock screen. It shows my notifications right in the middle in big white boxes. And since the power saver option is always on, there's always a white box in the middle of my screen. Before I reset it back to factory, notifications would just display a thin black bar at the top and disappear within 30 secs or so. Power Saver was just an icon at the top by the battery icon. It looked much nicer. There's also some other minor cosmetic changes.  Other things include I no longer have HTC themes and some other HTC apps.

Comment: I have the general idea of how to flash. I just can't seem to find WHAT I need to flash? I've found things like Marshmallow 6 for HTC (pre-rooted). But that's not what I need, is it? I don't need to root to flash according to the above comment.

Comment: Hmm, then you probably do need a flash. You don't need root to flash RUUs (factory firmwares), but those you found do need root and/or custom recovery. Whatever it is, I suggest supplementing more details by editing your question - you didn't even tell us your model and system build number (something like x.xx.xxx.x).

Comment: Sorry, I'll add more details. I haven't been able to find a RUU with stock marshmallow. I have one for stock Lollipop, though that's not what I need since that's what I already have.

Comment: I have found things like stock marshmallow for HTC One M8s and some Galaxy phones. Theres one on the official htc website for marshmallow 6.0 for One M8. Would those work for mine? Would they include Sense 7?

Comment: No, don't even think about cross flashing. As of now I haven't found such RUU either... All I could think of is the "hard" way i.e. flashing stock-based images with a custom recovery, but since you specifically stated that's not acceptable, I'm at a dead end too.